# puppet user account with no home dir?

Tags: macos, puppet, user-accounts

on my osx machine a while ago I was using puppet for a project at work however the time came when i had to remove puppet as i was no longer dealing with puppet and ya'know disk space (i my be a tad OCD)

anyway i dont normally log off my machine but when i did a few days ago i noticed there was a user account labeled 'puppet' when i tried to login there was no password (i tried puppet,my user account pw,and all other default passwords i could think of) but to no avail, i did a search around my disk noticed there was no trace of a puppet user anywhere, no home directory not even listed in the groups.

does anyone have any idea of how i can remove this ghost user?

Comment: can you see the user in `users & Groups`, then delete it from there.

Comment: if you read the question i did say it wasnt there

Comment: Does not compute. `I noticed there was a user account labeled 'puppet'` - *where* did you notice that if the user cannot be found anywhere on the system?

Comment: when i log out of my machine on the user select screen
sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I have made this set of commands based off of a few other posts. When uninstalled with a command, most or all of the files and folders will be automatically removed anyway, but I am including them for completeness. The dscl line is the most important for specifically removing the Puppet user on Mac OS X:

```
brew cask uninstall puppet
rm -i /usr/bin/puppet
rm -i /usr/sbin/puppet
rm -i /private/etc/puppet
rm -i /usr/share/doc/puppet
sudo dscl . delete /Users/puppet # Specifically for removing puppet user
sudo pkgutil --pkgs | grep puppet # Use the resulting list in the forget command below
sudo pkgutil --forget com.puppetlabs.puppet
```